# Mapping several strings to one key in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have a text file that looks (something) like this:

```
1825:lots of words
1899:a few more words
2018:other words
```

Now I want to create something like a hashmap where in the end I will output the most frequent words for 1, 2 etc. Is it possible to use the same key for different values?

I am having a very hard time understand lambda lines and reduceByKey.

Thanks

Comment: what is the expected output for the given example?

Comment: I am sorting the frequencies over the entire dataset, which words are the most common. Now I want to see which words are the most common by key, which is the number

Comment: First example in https://spark.apache.org/examples.html

Comment: Then are you looking for something like `{1 : {'words': 2, 'few': 1...}}`?

Comment: No, the entire string of each line should go to the same key. It's actually year. I will edit OP. There is years, from 1800-2018. Each year have a lot of lines and every year should have a list of all the words

Comment: I think *output the most frequent words* is a bit confusing here, since *the entire string of each line should go to the same key*. Could be an x vs y problem. I think it might be helpful to edit the question to contain sample output, that way we can steer you in the right direction